# У класса SKPhysicsContactDelegate не работает did, как исправить?

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

У меня вот такой для показа 2 node, при столкновении должен работать метод did, но он почему то не пашет, в чем проблема??

```
 let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: item)
            node.size = CGSize(width: node.size.width/2, height: node.size.height/2)
            node.name = "enum"
            node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node.size)
            node.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            enumMass.append(node)
player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerIngame3")
    player.size = CGSize(width: player.size.width/2.5, height: player.size.height/2.5)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: count(position: positionPlayer), y: frame.height*0.385)
    player.zPosition = 1
    player.name = "basket"

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
    player.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(player)
}
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Any...")
    }
```

Comment: Нет такого метода, `did`. Пишите название метода целиком, экстрасенсы в отпуску.

Comment: @kelin, вопрос закрыт. Я уже всё сделал

Answer (score 0):

Для определения столкновения свойство physicsBody!.isDynamic нужного узла должно быть true.

Из документации:
A Boolean value that indicates whether the physics body is moved by the physics simulation.
The default value is true. If the value is false, the physics body ignores all forces and impulses applied to it. This property is ignored on edge-based bodies; they are automatically static.